# pagination on data fetched using SQL query

Tags: plugins, php, posts, pagination, mysql

I am new with php and word press. I have a question that I am using a `sql query` in my `posts` to get data from my `data base`. Now the problem is that I have huge data on my `post` and I do not have idea how to apply `pagination` on the data which has been fetched using the `SQL query`. Here is the code which I am using in my `post`.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
// QUERY HERE TO COUNT TOTAL RECORDS FOR PAGINATION 
$total = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(distinct hadith_no, content) FROM muslim");
$post_per_page = 10;
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
$offset = ( $page * $post_per_page ) - $post_per_page;

// QUERY HERE TO GET OUR RESULTS 
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT hadith_no, content FROM muslim");
// PHP FOR EACH LOOP HERE TO DISPLAY OUR RESULTS
foreach($results as $row)
 {
 echo $row->hadith_no."  ".$row->content."<br>"; 
 }
// END OUR FOR EACH LOOP
?>
// PAGINATION HERE IN NICE BOOTSTRAP STYLES
<?php 
echo '<div class="pagination">';
echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
'format' => '',
'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
'total' => ceil($total / $post_per_page),
'current' => $page,
'type' => 'list'
));
echo '</div>';
?>
```

This give me a vertical pagination at the bottom of the page and still shows all the content on a single post instead of showing 10 posts. Any one who can help me using `pagination` on my `post` or edit this code so that I can have `pagination`.
Thank you.

Comment: You're fetching custom records and not Posts in the WP sense of the word.  Do you really need to use a separate table for this data, or would you be better off storing it as a custom post type?  If you can store it as custom posts, then you get the benefit of WP's API including pagination of lists of posts.

Comment: Thanks @AndyMacaulay-Brook for this response. There was a problem with my COUNT query which i have resolved and posted an answer for this question so that other users having this type of query can get help from here.

Comment: Great - it's fine to post your own answer. Make sure you accept it too!

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
// QUERY HERE TO COUNT TOTAL RECORDS FOR PAGINATION 
$total = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM muslim LIMIT 0,431) AS a");
$post_per_page = 10;
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
$offset = ( $page * $post_per_page ) - $post_per_page;

// QUERY HERE TO GET OUR RESULTS 
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT hadith_no, content FROM muslim LIMIT $post_per_page OFFSET $offset");

// PHP FOR EACH LOOP HERE TO DISPLAY OUR RESULTS
foreach($results as $row)
 {
 echo $row->hadith_no."  ".$row->content."<br>"; 
 }
// END OUR FOR EACH LOOP

?>
<?php 
echo '<div class="pagination">';
echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
'format' => '',
'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
'total' => ceil($total / $post_per_page),
'current' => $page,
'type' => 'list'
));
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Just edit the sql query according to your needs and this will work sweetly.